# Get all information from active layer after draw a polygon on WMS layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms

I want to get all the information from active Layer after draw a polygon on WMS layer

e.g. 1. area cover under Districts [{Name:abc, Area:10ha}]{Name:def,Area:20ha}];

```
var polygonDraw;
var layersArray=new Array();

var myView = new ol.View({
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([84.6525554, 20.1664539]),
    zoom: 6.89,
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 5
 }) 

const map = new ol.Map({
view: myView,
target: 'map'
//controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution: 
false}).extend(mapControls)
});

//Base layer
//Open Street Map
var defaultLayer=new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var baselayer=defaultLayer;
try {
baselayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    visible: true,
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });
} catch (error) {
 console.log('BaseLayer OSM: '+error);
}


 var districtboundarylayer;
 try {
  districtboundarylayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: geoserverUrl+'/DISTRICT/wms',
      params: {
          'LAYERS': 'DISTRICT:DistrictBoundary',
          'VERSION': '1.1.0'
      },
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'

  }),
  title: 'DistrictBoundary',
  visible: true
 });
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
} 

 const layerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
layers: ['baselayer','districtboundarylayer']
})

map.addLayer(layerGroup);


// DRAW INTERACTION
var drawSource = new ol.source.Vector()

var drawLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: drawSource,
style: new ol.style.Style({
fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
}),
stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: '#ffcc33',
  width: 2,
}),
image: new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 7,
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#ffcc33',
  }),
}),
})
});


var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
source: drawSource,
type: 'Polygon',
minPoints: 4,
freehand: false
});
map.addLayer(drawLayer);

var polygonsource = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
//var parser = new ol.format.WMSGetFeatureInfo();

var highlightOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
// style: (customize your highlight style here),
source: drawSource,
});
var polygonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: polygonsource
});
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
/* condition: new ol.events.condition.click, */
});

map.addLayer(highlightOverlay);
map.addLayer(polygonLayer);



$("#link_Draw").on('click', function (e) {
 map.addInteraction(draw);
});

draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
map.removeInteraction(draw);
})

$("#lnkResetDrawAoi").on('click', function (e) {
 drawSource.clear();
 map.removeInteraction(draw);
});




map.on('click', function (evt) {
try {
content.innerHTML = '';
var feature;
feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) 
{
  return feature;
});


if (feature) {
  console.log("Execute....");
  console.log(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
  var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  var props = feature.getProperties();
  //console.log(props);               
  content.innerHTML = "<h5>NFB Details</h5>"
    + "<div class='table-responsive my-table-sm'><table class='table 
table-sm table-bordered mb-0'><tr><td><strong>Division :</strong></td> 
<td>" + props.div + "</td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td><strong>Range :</strong></td><td>" + props.ran + "</td> 
</tr>"
    + "<tr><td><strong>Forest Block :</strong></td><td>" + props.fb + 
  "</td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td><strong>Area(Sq KM) :</strong></td><td>" + 
 props.area_sqkm + "</td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td><strong>Perimeter :</strong></td><td>" + props.perimeter 
 + "</td></tr></table></div>";
  overlay.setPosition(evt.coord);
}
else {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
}

} catch (error) {
console.log('MapOnClick : ' + error);
}
});
```

How to get AOI details like  Area cover from Dist1, Area Cover from Dist2  after draw polygon under two district?

Answer (score 2):

You can't draw a polygon on a WMS layer and get all the attribute information from a WMS layer under the polygon, because A WMS does not expose data in that way.  You can only get attribute information at a point location (a pixel coordinate) in the returned map image using a GetFeatureInfo request.

Comment: I can draw polygon

Comment: Yes, but you can't extract the attributes information using a polygon

Comment: Please suggest, how to solve? also i have all the data in postgresql

Comment: You can't do it through a WMS interface, using a polygon, even if all vector the data used to create the map images is in PostGIS.    You need to either send multiple GetFeaureInfo requests for all the pixel coordinates in your area of interest and then work out some way of resolving duplicate data , or configure a WFS to look at the data and query that